# How argv is filled?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, argv

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  printf("argc: %d\n",argc);
  for(int i=0;i<sizeof(argv);i++){
    printf("argv[%d] %s\n",i,argv[i]);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

compiles fine, when using it under a gnome terminal under a GNU/linux distribution

```
printTest one\ two three
argc: 3
argv[0] /data/local/tmp/printTest
argv[1] one two
argv[2] three
argv[3] (null)
```

I intentionally left a white space escaped and argv seems to behave really strangely.

Is this behaviour normal ? What is that null ? why argv creates a null pointer instead of just providing a shorter array ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof(argv)` is meaningless -- it's the size of a pointer (4 on your platform), which just coincidentally happens to be one more than the number of values in `argv` in this case.

Use `argc` here instead.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this behaviour normal ?

Yes, absolutely. With `one\ two` you specify that you want this to be one argument.

> What is that null ? why argv creates a null pointer instead of just providing a shorter array ?

It shows end of the array, and required by the standard. It makes it possible to loop through all arguments not using `argc`, e.g.:

```
while (*++argv) {
    // do something
}
```

But you also have a mistake in your code, as duskwuff pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `sizeof(argv)`: you'll just get the size of a pointer on your system, *not* the number of arguments.

Also note that `argv[argc]` is `NULL` according to the specification: there would be a `NULL` at `argv[argc]` regardless of your escaped space, or the number of arguments.

From *5.1.2.2.1/2*:

> argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This is to support the typical C-ish idiom:

```
for (char** arg = argv + 1; *arg; arg++)
{
    // process next arg
```

As you see, `argv` is 0-terminated array of strings.

The splitting of the input into the separate arguments is done by the shell, the language doesn't define it.